# как автоматически создавать TestSuite?

Tags: python, юнит-тесты, test-driven-development

Наверное тяжело будет тем кто не читал TDD Кента Бека, но думаю многие читали, поэтому прошу помощи. Уже 2 дня бьюсь, с ног сбился. В конце части 2 там получилась вот такая архитектура:

```
    class TestCase:
     def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
     def setUp(self):
        self.result = TestResult()
     def run(self, result):
        result.testStarted()
        self.setUp()
        try:
           method = getattr(self, self.name)
           method()
        except:
           result.testFailed()
        self.tearDown()
     def tearDown(self):
        pass

class WasRun(TestCase):
    def __init__(self, name):
        TestCase.__init__(self, name)
    def testMethod(self):
        self.wasRun=1
        self.log = self.log+"testMethod "
    def setUp(self):
        self.wasRun = None
        self.log = "setUp "
    def tearDown(self):
        self.log = self.log + "tearDown "
    def testBrokenMethod(self):
        raise Exception

class TestResult:
    def __init__(self):
        self.runCount = 0
        self.errorCount = 0
    def testStarted(self):
        self.runCount = self.runCount + 1
    def testFailed(self):
        self.errorCount = self.errorCount + 1
    def summary(self):
        return "%d run, %d failed" % (self.runCount, self.errorCount)

class TestSuite:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tests = []
    def add(self, test):
        self.tests.append(test)
    def run(self, result):
        for test in self.tests:
           test.run(result)       

class TestCaseTest(TestCase):
    def testTemplateMethod(self):
        test = WasRun("testMethod")
        test.run(self.result)
        assert("setUp testMethod tearDown " == test.log)
    def testResult(self):
        test = WasRun("testMethod")
        result = test.run(self.result)
        assert("1 run, 0 failed" == self.result.summary())
    def testFailedResult(self):
        test = WasRun("testBrokenMethod")
        result = test.run(self.result)
        assert("1 run, 1 failed" == self.result.summary())
    def testFailedResultFormatting(self):
        result = TestResult()
        result.testStarted()
        result.testFailed()
        assert("1 run, 1 failed" == self.result.summary())
    def testSuite(self):
        suite = TestSuite()
        suite.add(WasRun("testMethod"))
        suite.add(WasRun("testBrokenMethod"))
        result = TestResult()
        suite.run(self.result)
        assert("2 run, 1 failed" == self.result.summary())
```

Далее мы создаем тестовый набор, вот так:

```
suite = TestSuite()
result = TestResult()
suite.add(TestCaseTest("testTemplateMethod"))
suite.add(TestCaseTest("testResult"))
suite.add(TestCaseTest("testFailedResult"))
suite.add(TestCaseTest("testFailedResultFormatting"))
suite.add(TestCaseTest("testSuite"))
result = TestResult()
suite.run(result)
print result.summary()
```

И дальше Кент Бек пишет "Создать объект TestSuite автоматически на основе TestCase"

Не совсем понимаю, что это значит, подскажите пожалуйста. Я так понял: вместо тех 10 строк что я привел во втором листинге, тест должен запускаться одной:

```
TestCaseTest().run()
```

И после этой строки все тестовые методы, которые есть в тестовом классе должны выполняться.
Для этого нам нужен конструктор без параметров и метода `run()` без параметров. Но у нас уже есть конструктор и метод `run()` с параметрами, то есть нужна перегрузка, но перегрузки нет в Python. Значит нужно создать версии этих методов с параметрами по умолчанию. Хотя бы правильная идея?

Comment: Кажется у вас опечатка в классе `TestCaseTest` в методе `testSuite(self)` строка `suite = testSuite()` должна быть `suite = TestSuite()`

Comment: @PavelKarateev, спасибо, поправил

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров Прошу уточнить Вашу цель. Непонятно, что вы хотите достигнуть? Возможно научиться писать тесты к своему боевому коду и хотите упростить запуск тестов. А может быть пишите свой тестовый фреймворк? Или что-то еще?

Comment: Еще момент, первая строчка `result = TestResult()` по сути лишняя, вы `result` на 5 строчек ниже пересоздаете, не использовав до этого.

Answer (score 1):

Оригинальная цитата из книги:

> There is substantial duplication here, which we could eliminate if we had a way of constructing a suite automatically given a test class.

Да, под *here* понимаются как раз строчки `suite.add(...)`. Согласитесь - ручками каждый метод добавлять не самая удачная идея, может быть их там 100. Т.е. подразумевается что хотелось бы реализовать функционал, который соберет `TestSuite` из методов `TestCaseTest` автоматически сам, без нашего участия.

Реализовать это можно различными способами, думаю самый простой:

1. С помощью `dir()` получить методы `TestCaseTest` и отфильтровать те из них, что начинаются с `test*`
2. Создать `TestSuite`
3. Пройтись в цикле по списку методов из пункта 1 и добавить их в `TestSuite` при помощи `suite.add(TestCaseTest("имя_метода"))`
4. Теперь уже выполнить `suite.run(result)` на собранном `TestSuite`

Облечь эту логику можно, например, в отдельный класс TestLoader. Вот на github товарищ решал эту задачу: https://github.com/lenin/TDDbyExample/blob/7275d259132b44a5f24b116b4f61e47e421d7d35/PyTesting/tests.py и https://github.com/lenin/TDDbyExample/blob/7275d259132b44a5f24b116b4f61e47e421d7d35/PyTesting/testing.py получилось довольно аккуратно на мой взгляд.

P.S.: Интересная книжка, спасибо за наводку ;)

Answer (score 0):

Если Ваша цель упростить запуск тестов, то на этот случай моя рекомендация поставить пакет: `pip install nose` и использовать команду запуска: `nosetests -v`.

Comment: Не, моя цель написать этот запуск тестов самому